# Web3 bsc token send with python , gas fee calculation. ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'insufficient funds for gas * price + value'}

Tags: python, transactions, web3py, bsc

I want to write small python programme that if my acc2  have balance program will detect a positive balance and send it to my other wallet which acc1. Using web3 bsc to create transactions I got error:

`"ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'insufficient funds for gas * price + value'}"`

I'm not sure but probably trying to do something wrong with transaction. My acc2 balance got tokens and bnb for gas fees.

```
from decimal import Decimal
from web3 import Web3
import time
import json


bsc = "https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/"
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(bsc))
print(web3.isConnected())

# acc_collector_private_key = 'acc2_pkpkpkpk'
acc2_pk='pkpkpkpk'

token_contract = web3.toChecksumAddress('contract of token')

token_abi ='abi'

acc1 = '111111'
acc2    = '222222'
  


token = web3.eth.contract(address=token_contract, abi=token_abi) 
target_token_balance = token.functions.balanceOf(acc2).call() 
target_coin_name=token.functions.name().call()
target_coin_symbol=token.functions.symbol().call()

print(target_coin_name)
print(web3.fromWei(target_token_balance,'ether'))
print(target_coin_symbol)


nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(acc2)

tx = {
    'nonce' : nonce,
    'to' : acc1,
    'value':web3.toWei(target_token_balance,'ether'),
    'gas' : 21000,
    'gasPrice': web3.toWei('50','gwei')

}

signed_tx =web3.eth.account.signTransaction(tx,acc2_pk)
tx_hash = web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
trans = web3.toHex(tx_hash)

time.sleep(5)
transaction = web3.eth.get_transaction(trans)
print(transaction)

target_balance  = token.functions.balanceOf(acc2).call() 
print(target_balance)
```

Comment: What part of `'insufficient funds for gas * price + value'` isn't clear? "My acc2 balance got tokens and bnb for gas fees." How do you know? Did you try to check how much the transaction costs?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be fundamentally a question about how cryptocurrencies work, not a question about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it is because you put the `50 gwei` in high comma's.

```
from decimal import Decimal
from web3 import Web3
import time
import json


bsc = "https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/"
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(bsc))
print(web3.isConnected())

# acc_collector_private_key = 'acc2_pkpkpkpk'
acc2_pk='pkpkpkpk'

token_contract = web3.toChecksumAddress('contract of token')

token_abi ='abi'

acc1 = '111111'
acc2    = '222222'
  


token = web3.eth.contract(address=token_contract, abi=token_abi) 
target_token_balance = token.functions.balanceOf(acc2).call() 
target_coin_name=token.functions.name().call()
target_coin_symbol=token.functions.symbol().call()

print(target_coin_name)
print(web3.fromWei(target_token_balance,'ether'))
print(target_coin_symbol)


nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(acc2)

tx = {
    'nonce' : nonce,
    'to' : acc1,
    'value':web3.toWei(target_token_balance,'ether'),
    'gas' : 21000,
    'gasPrice': web3.toWei(50,'gwei') #<---- without the ""

}

signed_tx =web3.eth.account.signTransaction(tx,acc2_pk)
tx_hash = web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
trans = web3.toHex(tx_hash)

time.sleep(5)
transaction = web3.eth.get_transaction(trans)
print(transaction)

target_balance  = token.functions.balanceOf(acc2).call() 
print(target_balance)
```

Let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

balance in account < gasPrice*gasLimmit

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).